# DynamicServerError: Dynamic server usage: headers

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm on `NextJS=13.4.9` using the app router on `Node` runtime.

During `yarn build`:

```
- info Creating an optimized production build .node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

DynamicServerError: Dynamic server usage: headers
    at staticGenerationBailout (E:\repo\.next\server\chunks\4410.js:279:21)
    at headers (E:\repo\.next\server\chunks\4410.js:161:62)
    at buildRequestLike (E:\repo\.next\server\chunks\8460.js:2612:22)
    at auth (E:\repo\.next\server\chunks\8460.js:2633:8)
    at getPrismaUser (E:\repo\.next\server\chunks\5833.js:249:56)
    at SearchPage (E:\repo\.next\server\app\(dashboard)\dashboard\search\page.js:1344:18)
    at preloadComponent (E:\repo\node_modules\next\dist\server\app-render\preload-component.js:23:22) {
  digest: 'DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE'
}
```

This ruckus about dynamic everything repeats 3 times with the same stack trace (but with slightly different `triggerUncaughtException` messages, though none are particularly helpful):

```
Node.js v18.16.0
Static worker unexpectedly exited with code: 1 and signal: null
- info Creating an optimized production build ...node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);

...

Node.js v18.16.0
- info Creating an optimized production build ..node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
```

Before finally terminating with this:

```
Node.js v18.16.0

> Build error occurred
Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (E:\repo\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\index.js:1:11661)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (E:\repo\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\index.js:1:12599)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  type: 'WorkerError'
}
```

Given that the dynamic-header errors repeat a lot, I'm assuming `headers` is at the source of this somewhere. Googling and reading NextJS docs indicate that it is an issue with the compiler trying to make the routes static when they are in fact dynamic. So I went to the single API route I'm using `headers()` in (that isn't a part of the flow described in the stack trace) and added `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'`, likewise with `revalidate = 0`, but neither had any impact.

The components in the trace are all RSC and none of them invoke headers (except maybe the `auth` and `headers` files, but those belong to `Clerk.dev` and are out of my reach - and I've been using Clerk since the start of this project with no trouble).

Googling for the WorkerError info yields no relevant results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DynamicServerError: Dynamic server usage: headers` is a red herring for the purposes of getting to the root of this particular issue. I'm sure it's factually correct somewhere in this chain, but it's not at the heart of what went wrong with the code and it is at best really subtle about leading us in the right direction as to what is wrong with the code.

The real culprit is described in this line:

`triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);`

There's going to be a function call, presumably in the files mentioned in the stack trace, where the function itself is `async` but we've forgotten to `await` it.

I don't know why this generates the error as shown above instead of the usual rabble about `Promise<such-and-so> is incompatible with type 'string | null'` and all of that - but - it is nevertheless the source of the error.

So find this line:

```js
const variable = asyncFunction();
```

and turn it into this:

```js
const variable = await asyncFunction();
```